# Sending email to admin when form is filled

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer, email

Website source:http://www.salefee.com/

I have made a form on website to send a message to admin after filling the form(using php).
My html form is as given below:

```
<html>
<body>
 <!-- Contact form -->
              <form autocomplete="on" action='./contact.php' method='post'>
              <div class="form-horizontal contact-form" role="form">
                <fieldset>
                  <legend>Contact</legend>
                  <div class="r1 row form-group">
                    <div class="c1 col-sm-6 col-md-6" style="float:left;">
                      <input class="form-control1" id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name *" required autocomplete="on">
                    </div>
                    <div class="c2 col-sm-6 col-md-6" >
                      <input class="form-control1" id="lname" name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name *" required autocomplete="on">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="r2 row form-group">
                    <div class="c1 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <input class="form-control2" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email *" required autocomplete="on">
                    </div>
                    <div class="c2 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <input class="form-control3" id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Phone" autocomplete="on">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="r4 row form-group">
                    <div class="c1 col-md-12">
                      <input class="form-control4" id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject *" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="r5 row form-group">
                    <div class="c1 col-md-12">
                      <textarea class="form-control5" id="message" name="message" rows="10" placeholder="Message *" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="r6 row form-group" style="text-align:center; margin-right:16%">
                    <div class="c1 col-md-12" >
                      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger submit-form-contact" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </div>
              </form>
              <!-- End Contact form -->
</body>
</html>
```

My contact.php file is as given below:

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
  $to_email = "info@salefee.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

  //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
  if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
      'type'=>'error',
      'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST.'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
  }

  //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
  $user_fname   = filter_var($_POST["fname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $user_lname   = filter_var($_POST["lname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $user_email   = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $user_phone   = filter_var($_POST["phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  //$user_company = filter_var($_POST["user_company"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  //$user_website = filter_var($_POST["user_website"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $subject      = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $message      = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  //additional php validation
  if (strlen($user_fname) < 3) { // If length is less than 3 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'First Name is too short or empty.'));
    die($output);
  }
  if (strlen($user_lname) < 3) { // If length is less than 3 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Last Name is too short or empty.'));
    die($output);
  }
  if (!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email.'));
    die($output);
  }
  if (!filter_var($user_phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)) { //check for valid numbers in phone number field
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number.'));
    die($output);
  }
  if (strlen($subject) < 1) { //check emtpy subject
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required.'));
    die($output);
  }
  if (strlen($message) < 3) { //check emtpy message
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
    die($output);
  }

  //email body
  $message_body = "Name   : ".$user_fname." ".$user_lname."\r\nEmail  : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone  : ".$user_phone."\r\nCompany: ".$user_company."\r\nWebsite: ".$user_website."\r\n\r\n".$message;

  //proceed with PHP email.
  $headers = 'From: '.$user_fname.''."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$user_email.''."\r\n".
  'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

  $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

  if (!$send_mail)
  {
    //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
  } else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_fname.', thank you for your email.'));
    die($output);
  }
}
?>
```

The problem is that after clicking submit I am not getting any email.The URL after submitting becomes like `http://www.salefee.com/?fname=Test&lname=name&email=test%40email.com&phone=1234567890&subject=testsubject&message=testmessage` I want to recieve an email when user click submits button to the mentioned email id. Please help me with this code.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the content of the file which it asking to save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If server wants to save your file, there is problem with your PHP server, probably you have no PHP server installed or cant read .php files or has bade configuration.

NOTE:
First, your form tag must including action link where to redirect after submit and method, sumethimg like this : `<form action='./contact.php' method='post'></form>`, if this is not filled, your submit form will be submitted in same file.

Second, if you are not submitting with AJAX you need to remove this part of code in contact.php

```
//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
      'type'=>'error',
      'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST.'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
}
```